# CasperJS require('utils').dump(this.logs) is undefined

Tags: casperjs

I'm writing a CasperJS script and would like to dump the entire contents of what has been written to the logs since execution start. In the casperjs [documentation](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/logging.html), it says,

> You can also dump a JSON log of your Casper suite just by rendering the contents of the Casper.logs property

Unfortunately, when I use the example code from the documentation, am getting 'undefined' from the casper.logs value. Here is sample code:

```
casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'info'
});
casper.start();
casper.thenOpen('http://casperjs.org', function() {
    this.log("this is a log", 'info');
    this.log(this.getTitle(), 'info');
});
casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
    this.log(this.getTitle(), 'info');
    require('utils').dump(this.logs);
});
casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```

And here is the output of this code:

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 4 steps
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/4 http://casperjs.org/ (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] this is a log
[info] [phantom] CasperJS, a navigation scripting and testing utility for PhantomJS and SlimerJS
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/4: done in 913ms.
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 4/4 http://phantomjs.org/ (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] PhantomJS | PhantomJS
undefined
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 4/4: done in 1340ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 4 steps in 1359ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [code](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/modules/casper.js#L1333) you should use:

```js
require('utils').dump(this.result.log);
```

There is no such thing as `this.logs` anymore.

Since this is not really documented, it may change in future versions. I suggest you either register to the `log` event or use `this.echo`.

Comment: Thank you! You gave me 3 options.